# Regression of dataset with many x values per y value

Tags: weighted-regression, total-least-squares

I am performing a total least squares regression in which I have many x observations for a given y observation. The x observations are normally distributed.

I am aware I could do some sort of weighting using the variance of x at each y, but do I have to? Could I not just input every each x,y pair and run the regression? Would the results be the same?

Comment: Can you give an example of your data set?  If I understand correctly, you have more than one value of $x_1$ for a single value of $y$?  If that's the case, I guess I would ask why that is, which would influence how you create your model.

Comment: The dataset is ground penetrating radar measurements(GPR) (~x) taken over asphalt with a known air void content(~y). There are thousands of individual measurements taken over a single location. I do not have a sample of the dataset at this time.

Comment: You seem to have flipped the response and predictor here. The $y$ in your experiment is not a random variable (you say it's known) -- the $x$'s are. Presumably the reason why you're calling it the $y$ here is you want to later use the derived relationship to predict air void content from GPR measurements (like inverse regression).

Comment: Glen_b, you are correct, that is the end goal of the regression. Is it incorrect to use the GPR data as the x value?